# ajax post hide a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am having an issue getting my Ajax post to disable the button that I have to submit the data. Below is my code, I've looked around and everything looks right to me but its not disabling the button, I've tried to use `$("#refreshButton").attr("disabled", true);` and `$("#refreshButton").removeAttr("disabled");` but it didn't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            $("#refreshButton").attr("disabled", true); 
            request.setRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorizationToken);
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            //Do Something here
        });
        },
        error: function (x, status, error) {
            //errors                
        }
    });
})
$("#refreshButton").removeAttr("disabled");
```

This is my button:

```
<input id="refreshButton" type="button" onclick="RefreshDataSubmit();" value="Refresh"/>
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JS console?

Comment: No im not. I just get the logging messages I put in the code but not a single error.

Comment: use complete function and put your refreshButton inside of it using $(element).attr("disabled", false); `$.ajax({complete: function(){ enable again } });`

Comment: for full browser compatibility, disabled should be set the value 'disabled' for disabling an element, or the attribute must be removed for enabling the element.

Comment: below answers would work but your title says hide so $("#refreshButton").hide();

Comment: @codetantrik on new jquery versions, it's prefered to use .prop()

Comment: @roasted Of course, but can also be sync if `async` param set to false ;)

Comment: @Jimbo  oh ya, didn't notice it, thx. But anyway, ajax should never be set as synchron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to enable the button once the ajax call has completed, and you would do that in the `always` handler as you shouldn't be using async false, and that will always enable the button regardless of the result from the ajax call (fail or done).
The problem right now is that you're enabling the button outside the DOM ready function, so either the selector doesn't find the element, or it's executed before the ajax call, as document ready is async.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            $("#refreshButton").prop("disabled", true); 
            request.setRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorizationToken);
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml"
    }).done(function (xml) {
         //Do Something here
    }).fail(function (x, status, error) {
         //errors                
    }).always(function() {
         $("#refreshButton").removeProp("disabled");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            $("#refreshButton").prop("disabled", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorizationToken);
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {                
            //Do Something here
        },
        complete:function(){$("#refreshButton").prop("disabled", false);},
        error: function (x, status, error) {
          //errors                
        }...
```